# Updating specific mySQL record by link in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on a membership database (using mySQL), and I want to be able to update my records through a webpage (build using a combination of html, css, javascript and php).

The records are being output to a table, and the ID is set as a link, with this I want to be able to click the link and update that specific record.

The code to display the database in a table is as follows:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo 
    "<tr>
        <td><a href='../rediger-medlem.html' target='_blank'>".$row["MedlemID"]."</a></td>
        <td>".$row["Fornavn"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Etternavn"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Adresse"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Mobil"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Epost"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Dato Innmeldt"]."</td>
        <td>".$row["Betalt Innv. År"]."</td>
    </tr>";
```

And the code for updating the entry is:

```
$sql = "UPDATE medlemmer (Fornavn, Etternavn, Adresse, Mobil, Epost, `Dato Innmeldt`, `Betalt Innv. År`)
SET ('$fornavn', '$etternavn', '$adresse', '$mobil', '$epost', '$datoInnmeldt', '$betaltInnvÅr')"
WHERE MedlemID = $medlemId;
```

My issue is that I cannot seem to be able to define $medlemId correctly by clicking the link.

Looking for any tips to get this to work properly, I've tested defining a variable, but through trail and error and forum browsing it doesn't seem that you can set variables by links.

Appriciate any help. If anything is unclear, dont desitate to ask for clarity

Comment: That isn't how UPDATE works. Please read the documentation on it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using insert query

Update query like `UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMNNAME = "VALUE"`

if multiple field than separated by comma

`UPDATE TABLENAME SET COLUMNNAME = "VALUE", COLUMNNAME1 = "VALUE1"`